# Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=9565

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different environments develop and live almost both are same
But the above (in title) warning is occurred in develop mode only. 
Before this warning I am also getting error message as "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted". This happened only in develop mode.

Using PHP version 5.6 with mysql (not mysqli).

Comment: Increase php `memory_limit = 1024M;` in php.ini or Use this  `<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 64M
</IfModule>` in **.htaccess** file.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't worked

Comment: Actually your application trying to allocate Memory of **268.435456MB** which is not present. So you are getting this error. Have you checked  in your php info file, Try this `<IfModule mod_php5.c> php_value memory_limit 1024M </IfModule>` in .htaccess file and Create a file called phpinfo.php and add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and run it and check memory allocated or not.

Comment: And also check your db max upload size `upload_max_filesize = 512M` and   `post_max_size = 512M` . Because your DB doesn't have enough configurations to accept the Query.

Comment: thanks every one .
Problem was solved the issue is one of my developer making wrong recursive function that's why more memory allocated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks every one . Problem was solved the issue is one of my developer making wrong recursive function that's why more memory allocated